# Add where condition in hook_views_data with join?

Tags: 7, views

I want to join my custom table with node fields. In my custom table there is a nid field for which I have used join and another is uid field for which I want a condition where uid = current_user_uid. But adding this in custom handler it giving me duplicate record if I have three [nid, uid] pair.

For ex : I have [1, 1] and [1, 2] and [2, 1] pair then it should be give me first and third record if I am logged in using first user and second pair if I am logged in using 2nd user. But it is giving me all the records.

My Code sample :

```
  $data = array();

  // Create a new group by which the of this module plugins would be grouped.
  $data['custom_table']['table']['group'] = t('Event');

  // Join the table with default node table.
  $data['custom_table']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );  

  $data['custom_table']['id'] = array(
    'title' => t('Unique Id'),
    'help' => t('Unique Id id.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_custom_field_id',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
```

## Edit :

I didn't found any way to do this in my custom module. Somehow I managed to do it with view's template file.